How to implement join order optimization using dynamic programming in Python?
I am working on a project to optimize SQL queries by determining the optimal join order using dynamic programming in Python.
Context
I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database and need to calculate the join costs for different combinations of tables. I have already written functions to calculate the scan cost of a table and the join cost between two sets of tables.
Here is an excerpt of my current code:
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname="dbname",
    user="postgres",
    password="password",
    host="localhost",
    port="port"
)

def calculate_cost(solution, conn):
    total_cost = 0
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            for table in solution:
                cur.execute(f"EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, FORMAT JSON) SELECT * FROM {table};")
                explain_result = cur.fetchone()[0]
                explain_json = json.loads(explain_result) if isinstance(explain_result, str) else explain_result
                total_cost += float(explain_json['Plan']['Total Cost'])
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error calculating cost: {e}")
        conn.rollback()
    return total_cost

def remove_lower_cost_equivalents(partial_solutions, conn):
    min_cost = float('inf')
    best_solutions = set()
    for solution in partial_solutions:
        total_cost = calculate_cost(solution, conn)
        if total_cost < min_cost:
            min_cost = total_cost
            best_solutions = {solution}
        elif total_cost == min_cost:
            best_solutions.add(solution)
    return best_solutions

def DynamicProgramming(Rels, conn):
    partialsolutions = {frozenset({rel}) for rel in Rels}
    for i in range(1, len(Rels)):
        new_partial_solutions = set()
        for partial_tree in partialsolutions:
            for rel in Rels:
                if rel not in partial_tree:
                    new_partial_tree = partial_tree.union({rel})
                    new_partial_solutions.add(new_partial_tree)
        partialsolutions = remove_lower_cost_equivalents(new_partial_solutions, conn)
    optimal_solution = next(iter(partialsolutions))
    optimal_cost = calculate_cost(optimal_solution, conn)
    optimal_order = list(optimal_solution)
    return len(Rels), optimal_cost, optimal_order

# Running the code
relations = ['title', 'movie_info', 'complete_cast']
nb_relations, cost, optimal_order = DynamicProgramming(relations, conn)
print(f"Number of relations: {nb_relations}")
print(f"Optimal cost: {cost}")
print(f"Optimal order: {optimal_order}")
conn.close()

here are the results :
nb_Relation,DP_Cost,Runtime,Optimal_Order
3,253206.22,30.894135236740112,"['complete_cast', 'title', 'movie_info']"

I am encountering issues with the join costs being very high, and I am unsure how to improve the implementation to get more realistic costs. Additionally, I would like to know if there is a method to pre-calculate and store the join costs between all combinations of tables and then use them to optimize the join order.

Why do you think the join order matters?

the join order is a critical factor in SQL query optimization because it directly influences the execution time, resource usage, and overall efficiency of the query. Optimizing join order helps achieve better performance, scalability, and resource management in database systems.

The optimization and query planning is done by the database, that's not something you have to do in your application. At least not for PostgreSQL. Changing the order for a LEFT JOIN also changes the question you're asking. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-joins.html and many discussions about this subject. the planner is free to join the given tables in any order., in rare occasions you might want to change this behavior. I would only do that when you have a problem that you can't fix any other way

Keep in mind that SQL is declarative, not procedural. You tell your server what you require, and its query planner works out the most efficient way to satisfy the query, based on indexes, the columns you want, the distribution of values in the columns, your WHERE predicates and many other criteria. The cost of retrieving every column (SELECT *) of every row (absent WHERE clause)/of a table worth optimizing is almost never interesting in practice. And the query planner modules have literally hundreds of programmer years of very sophisticated development in them.

Thank you for your feedback. I understand that PostgreSQL boasts a sophisticated query optimizer that handles join order optimization automatically. However, my research project focuses on developing and evaluating new approaches to join order optimization, especially for complex queries or large datasets.
